DNS lookup issue for two control-plane nodes of kubernetes cluster
I have this DNS Issue for control-plane-nodes 2 and 3 of my k8s cluster :
control-plane-node-1 :
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# nslookup google.com 10.96.0.10
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.36.46
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:400e:803::200e

control-plane-node-2 :
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-2:~# nslookup google.com 10.96.0.10
;; communications error to 10.96.0.10#53: timed out
;; communications error to 10.96.0.10#53: timed out
;; communications error to 10.96.0.10#53: timed out
;; no servers could be reached

control-plane-node-3 :
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-3:~# nslookup google.com 10.96.0.10
;; communications error to 10.96.0.10#53: timed out
;; communications error to 10.96.0.10#53: timed out
;; communications error to 10.96.0.10#53: timed out
;; no servers could be reached

How to thoroughly and correctly debug the coredns of the control-plane-2/3 nodes in order to make them work?

Use the following methods to diagnose the CoreDNS problem on your Kubernetes control plane nodes 2 and 3:
First check the CoreDNS pod status by using the below command,
Kubectl get pods -n kube-system

It should be in the running state. If they’re not running check their logs by using the below command,
Kubectl logs -n kube - system
<coredns-pod-name>

And next verify coreDNS configuration by using below command and ensure that configuration is set up correctly.
kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap coredns

Verify that control plane nodes 2 and 3 can reach the coreDNS service by using the below command,
 Kubectl exec -it  <pod-name>  -n
 Kube-system – nslookup <coredns-service>

And verify that the ip address 10.96.0.10 is correctly assigned to the coreDNS service by using below command,
 Kubectl get svc -n kube-system 

And if you suspect the coreDNS service is in a bad state then try restarting the coreDNS pods:
 Kubectl delete pod -n kube-system
 <coredns-pod-name>

Note: Also make sure that kubelet is properly configured on the nodes 2 and 3 and if you use tools like curl or ping use them to test connectivity to the coreDNS service from nodes 2 & 3. Also check if there are any firewall rules that may block traffic between nodes or to DNS service.
